# Hasse Diagrams - Relations

Tags: relations, order-theory

I have the following question:

Draw the Hasse diagram for the following partially-ordered set:

> The relation $X$ is a subset of $Y$, on the set
>       $\{ \{0\}, \{2\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,2\}, \{2,4\}, \{0,1,2\}, \{0,2,4\} \}$.

I have drawn Hasse diagrams with simple sets, (i.e. {1,2,3,4,5}) however nothing like this. How would I go about ordering this from top to bottom, does the X and Y notations relate to the first and second digit of each element, and if so what is the third digit?

Should it look like this?

[image]

Comment: Firstly you should identify the order on the given set. Do you know what it is?

Comment: Hmm no, the above information is all ive been given for the question

Comment: The order is implied. You should order the sets by inclusion. Can you take it from here?

Comment: No unfortunately not, would it be possible for you to show me the first branch so I might have an idea as to how to start the diagram?

Comment: Let $A=\{ \{0\}, \{2\}, \{0,1\}, \{0,2\}, \{2,4\}, \{0,1,2\}, \{0,2,4\} \}$. The order $\leq$ on $A$ is defined as follows: $\forall X,Y\in A\left(X\leq Y\iff X\subseteq Y\right)$. Do you realise this? If you do, what's keeping from drawing the diagram?

Comment: Ok I've tried the diagram, my original post has been amended to include it

Comment: The diagram is correct.I suggest that you edit it out of the question and post it as an answer so this question doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for your help

Comment: @GitGud is $ \{0,1\} \subseteq \{0,2,4\}$?

Comment: @ManjoyDas Absolutely not. I was incorrect in saying the diagram is correct. There two edges that should be removed.